# Create a list of lists of non-duplicated elements

Tags: python, unique

I have a list of lists containing a name, a score and a team. If there are duplicates of the name and team, discard those instances and do not add them to the new list. Only inner lists with unique - name and team combinations - can be in the new list. Order of the inner list is important

I have tried combinations of list(), set(), map() and tuple().

```
scores = [['Ali', 15, 'Zebra'], ['Mo', 20, 'Donkey'], ['Ali', 18, 'Zebra'], ['Liz', 20, 'Mouse']]
```

The new list cannot contain either of the duplicates for: name/team.

Retaining the order of the inner lists is important.

```
new_scores = [['Mo', 20, 'Donkey'],['Liz', 20, 'Mouse']]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the 3rd element in inner-lists the team?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306844/custom-comparison-functions-for-built-in-types-in-python
you need to implement a comparator and use it when adding data to the the Set in order to have unique values

Comment: @LoukasPap Yep, the 3rd element in the inner-lists is the team name. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can count the name/team combinations in one pass with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). With that you can filter out only those items with a count of 1:

```
from collections import Counter

scores = [['Ali', 15, 'Zebra'], ['Mo', 20, 'Donkey'], ['Ali', 18, 'Zebra'], ['Liz', 20, 'Mouse']]

counts = Counter((name, team) for name, score, team in scores)

[item for item in scores if counts[(item[0], item[2])] == 1]
# [['Mo', 20, 'Donkey'], ['Liz', 20, 'Mouse']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without using Python's Counter:

First, replace middle index(the number) with `''`

Next, keep items with only one occurrence

At last, bring back the middle index(the number) to lists

```
import copy

scores = [['Ali', 15, 'Zebra'], ['Mo', 20, 'Donkey'], ['Ali', 18, 'Zebra'], ['Liz', 20, 'Mouse']]
original_scores = copy.deepcopy(scores)


for i in range(len(scores)):
    scores[i][1] = ''


one_occurance = [i for i in scores if scores.count(i) == 1]
indexes = [scores.index(i) for i in scores if scores.count(i) == 1]

for i in range(len(one_occurance)):
    one_occurance[i][1] = original_scores[indexes[i]][1]

print(one_occurance)
# [['Mo', 20, 'Donkey'], ['Liz', 20, 'Mouse']]
```

Answer (score 0):

With for loop, make a hash of `name, animal` and count duplicates . values having 1 count, are non duplicate and are required result.

```
>>> scores = [['Ali', 15, 'Zebra'], ['Mo', 20, 'Donkey'], ['Ali', 18, 'Zebra'], ['Liz', 20, 'Mouse']]
>>> 
>>> result = {}
>>> for sublist in scores:
...     if (sublist[0], sublist[2]) not in result:
...             result[(sublist[0], sublist[2])] = [sublist, 0]
...     result[(sublist[0], sublist[2])][1] += 1
... 
>>> solution = [i[0] for _, i in result.items() if i[1]==1]
>>> solution
[['Mo', 20, 'Donkey'], ['Liz', 20, 'Mouse']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use libraries, you could build a dictionary using the name/team pairs as keys and the sublists as value for keys that are only present once (and None for duplicates).   Then filter the values of the dictionary to get the resulting scores list:

```
scores = [['Ali', 15, 'Zebra'], ['Mo', 20, 'Donkey'], 
          ['Ali', 18, 'Zebra'], ['Liz', 20, 'Mouse']]

uniques = dict()
uniques.update( ((n,t),None if (n,t) in uniques else (n,p,t))
                for n,p,t in scores )

*new_scores, = filter(None,uniques.values())

print(new_scores)
[('Mo', 20, 'Donkey'), ('Liz', 20, 'Mouse')]
```

*Note: The initial item order is preserved because dictionaries retain the order of key additions (unless you're using a very old version of Python)*

**...**

Using sets, you can first build a set of all name/team pairs that are present.  From that build a set of the ones that are duplicates (removing from the set of seen name/teams as you go).  And finally filter the scores on name/teams that are not duplicates:

```
seen = {(n,t) for n,_,t in scores}
dups = {(n,t) for n,_,t in scores if (n,t) not in seen or seen.discard((n,t))}
new_scores = [(n,p,t) for n,p,t in scores if (n,t) not in dups]
```

**...**

You could also use this (rather inefficient) one liner:

```
new_scores = [(n,p,t) for n,p,t in scores 
              if sum((n2,t2)==(n,t) for n2,_,t2 in scores)==1]
```

or this two-line variant:

```
pairs      = [(n,t)   for n,_,t in scores]
new_scores = [(n,p,t) for n,p,t in scores if pairs.count((n,t))==1]
```

Answer (score -1):

In here we are taking a list that has duplicate values after that again I am just taking a empty list now to fetch the duplicate value we are applying for loop on the each element that is present in the list li and as well as an internal loop for the sub list element and after that the condition statement and logical operator if the element are duplicate we are appending the element as a list in the list= list2.

```py
li1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
list2 = []

for element in li1:
    if not any(element in sublist for sublist in list2):
        list2.append([element])

print(list2)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the information, don't add it in the comments.